# Selenium Error -- Explicit wait does not work

Tags: java, selenium

Code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement btn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='_1vp5 f_click']")));
btn.click();
```

Error:

> System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:882)
>       at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:881)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:43)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
>       ... 1 more

Comment: does this only happen with that xpath?

Comment: yes it was happening with that xpath only

Answer (score 1):

I think the visibilityOfElementLocated should have two arguments.
First -- your selector.
Second -- your actual selector on the page.

For your case should be like this (code in Python):

```
ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='_1vp5']")))
```

Comment: this answer did not help, what helped was using (By.XPATH, "//[@class='_1vp5']") instead of (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='_1vp5 f_click']")

Comment: You are right. It's was my mistake. Thanks. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working now:

```
WebElement btn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='_1vp5']")));
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Ok, you can set tick near my answer. Thanks.